# Why use a context path when can just deploy to webapps folder

Tags: tomcat

Why use a context path to describe where an app is located when it can be just deployed to webapps. Are there advantages of using one over the other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File permissions and security, especially in a multi-hosted environment, for one.